# How to add write permissions to everyone for AWS s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using an s3 bucket and I would like to grant write permission to everyone. The AWS console is not allowing me to do this instead it is asking to use AWS CLI to enable write permission. How can enable write permissions to everyone using AWS CLI

Comment: Public write access is a very bad idea. What do you want to achieve? Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: @Marcin I am  working on a Django project in which the users can upload photos to the site and am using s3 bucket for serving static files

Comment: Django [supports](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) S3. So your users would upload imges to your application first, and the application would store them in S3. No need for public read/write access for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Granting public Read access is acceptable from a security perspective if the data is intended to be public, or it is files for a public website. This can be granted via a Bucket Policy. You will also need to **deactivate Block Public Access on the bucket**.

Granting public Write access is not a good idea. For example, somebody could upload the entire world's collection of copyright movies. You would be charged for the storage and you would be in violation of copyright laws. Similarly, if you allow public Read access, you would be charged for all Data Transfer charges for downloading content from the bucket, which could be considerable.

Instead, **your application should control access to Amazon S3**. If a user is permitted to upload to your S3 bucket, your application permit [Uploading objects using presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html). This way, a user can only upload if your application permits it, and there can be restrictions on things like filetype, size and filename.

Similarly, it is possible to use [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) to grant time-limited Read access to private objects stored in Amazon S3.

So, yes, you can grant public Write access via the S3 management console, but I would advise against it.

Comment: Nice answer, very helpful for a S3 newbie

Answer (score 2):

John is correct in that in 99% of cases you should not enable write access to a bucket for everyone.

However, in my case I am developing a tool for uploading objects to S3 and I want to test all possible edge cases, including uploading to an S3 bucket as an anonymous user. As the question indicates, the AWS Management Console does indeed not let you enable public write access to a bucket (for good reason! I bet this caused way too many incidents back when it let you do this!).

So if you are in my situation, then you can run:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket bucketname --acl public-read-write
```

Once you've completed your testing, you can re-run the command with `--acl private` to make the bucket private again. Or you can use the AWS Management Console, as it will let you disable write access.